# Doesn't display custom grid values unless I sort in Admin Panel

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid

I have a problem my Admin Grid for my custom column is empty unless I sort by it.

Here are my two files I used to create the custom column.
`local/Sean/CustomerGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php`

```
<?php
class Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid{
    /**
     * override the _prepareCollection to add an other attribute to the grid
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer, use the line below
            ->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')
            //if the attribute belongs to the customer address, comment the line above and use the one below
            //->joinAttribute('mobile', 'customer_address/mobile', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        //code from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()
        //since calling parent::_prepareCollection will render the code above useless
        //and you cannot call in php parent::parent::_prepareCollection()
        if ($this->getCollection()) {

            $this->_preparePage();

            $columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
            $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
            $filter   = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);

            if (is_null($filter)) {
                $filter = $this->_defaultFilter;
            }

            if (is_string($filter)) {
                $data = $this->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            }
            else if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
            }
            else if(0 !== sizeof($this->_defaultFilter)) {
                $this->_setFilterValues($this->_defaultFilter);
            }

            if (isset($this->_columns[$columnId]) && $this->_columns[$columnId]->getIndex()) {
                $dir = (strtolower($dir)=='desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
                $this->_columns[$columnId]->setDir($dir);
                $this->_setCollectionOrder($this->_columns[$columnId]);
            }

            if (!$this->_isExport) {
                $this->getCollection()->load();
                $this->_afterLoadCollection();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * override the _prepareColumns method to add a new column after the 'email' column
     * if you want the new column on a different position just change the 3rd parameter
     * of the addColumnAfter method to the id of your desired column
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumnAfter('modify_catalog_labor', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Labor'),
            'index'     => 'modify_catalog_labor',
            'type'      => 'decimal'
        ),'email');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

`local/Sean/CustomerGrid/etc/config.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerGrid>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomerGrid>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>Sean_CustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My issue is when I am not sorting by "labor" it looks like this:
[image]

But when I sort by labor it shows up?:
[image]

If possible I don't want to sort by labor to make it show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below this

```
->addAttributeToSelect('mobile')
```

add this

```
->addAttributeToSelect('modify_catalog_labor')
```

Comment: Thank you Marius! you're awesome could you help me with one more thing? I'll open a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
```

Add

```
->addAttributeToSelect('modify_catalog_labor')
```